# Keep column width in Word document on page break for inserted HTML table

Tags: html, ms-word, openxml

I'm automatically generating a word document using the OpenXML 2.0 SDK. There is a template Word file containing Content Controls which will be replaced by the actual content while generating the final Word file.

One of the content controls is being replaced by a HTML table.

HTML table:

```
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="font-family:Arial; font-size:10.5pt; border-collapse:collapse">
    <tr style="font-weight:bold;font-style:italic">
        <td width="45"/>
        <td style="padding-right:2px;">Traktandum</td>
        <td style="padding-right:2px;">Wer</td>
        <td style="padding-right:2px;" width="100">Wann</td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="background-color:#D8D8D8;font-weight:bold">
        <td style="padding-left:5px">1.</td>
        <td>Allgemein</td>
        <td/>
        <td/>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="padding-left:5px" valign="top">1.1</td>
        <td valign="top">Begrüssung</td>
        <td valign="top" />
        <td valign="top" />
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td/>
        <td valign="top" height="140">
            <ul>
                <li/>
            </ul>
        </td>
        <td/>
        <td/>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td/>
        <td>Mein Zusatztext zur Begrüssung</td>
        <td/>
        <td/>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td/>
        <td  style="font-weight:bold;color:red">Meine Bemerkung zur Begrüssung</td>
        <td/>
        <td/>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="padding-left:5px" valign="top">1.2</td>
        <td valign="top">Divers</td>
        <td valign="top" />
        <td valign="top" />
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td/>
        <td valign="top" height="140">
            <ul>
                <li/>
            </ul>
        </td>
        <td/>
        <td/>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td/>
        <td>Zusatztext divers</td>
        <td/>
        <td/>
    </tr>
    <tr style="font-weight:bold;font-style:italic">
        <td/>
        <td>protokolleintrag diverses</td>
        <td/>
        <td/>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td/>
        <td  style="font-weight:bold;color:red">Bemerkung diverses</td>
        <td/>
        <td/>
    </tr>
    <tr style="background-color:#D8D8D8;font-weight:bold">
        <td style="padding-left:5px">2.</td>
        <td>eDecide</td>
        <td/>
        <td/>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Which results in following in the Word document:
[image: Generated table]
Up to here everything works as expected!

**Issue**: It must be supported to add page breaks within the table, while keeping the column widths in both split tables, but when doing this, the first and the column widths get modified (auto) width after the page break, as they haven't got any content:
[image: Table split by page break]

If adding a table in Word, the behavior is not the same and the column widths are being kept accross pages (they aren't linked anymore after the page break -> if a column width changes on page 1 it wont change on page 2, but this is fine for my use case):
[image: Table split inside Word]

**Question**: Is there a way (CSS or other) to tell Word to keep the column widths from the initial table when adding a page break within a table which has been added as a HTML table?

Comment: You could try laying out the table as you wish in Word, then doing save as HTML. Try feeding that "HTML" back into Word to see whether it behaves as you expect.

Comment: @JasonPlutext Thanks for the good idea. Setting a width for every cell in the HTML table solved this problem. Even when resizing a cell prior to inserting the page break, it behaves as expected.